How to create multiple azure devops pipeline by calling objects from single or multiple csv files?
How can I create multiple pipelines in Microsoft Azure DevOps by calling objects from single or multiple csv files?
How can the script pick up blank space from one of the excel columns? For example Folder Path
This is what I have so far.
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\*******\Downloads\excel\notes.csv" 

$pipelineName = $pipelineVariables.name
$pipelineFolderPath = $pipelineVariables.FolderPath
$pipelineDescription = $pipelineVariables.Description
$pipelineRepostiory = $pipelineVariables.Repository
$pipelineBranch = $pipelineVariables.Branch
$pipelineYamlPath = $pipelineVariables.YamlPath


az pipelines create --name $pipelineName --folder-path $pipelineFolderPath --description $pipelineDescription --repository $pipelineRepostiory --branch $pipelineBranch --yml-path $pipelineYamlPath

The value for variables.
$pipelineName = $pipelineVariables.name
$pipelineFolderPath = $pipelineVariables.FolderPath
$pipelineDescription = $pipelineVariables.Description
$pipelineRepostiory = $pipelineVariables.Repository
$pipelineBranch = $pipelineVariables.Branch
$pipelineYamlPath = $pipelineVariables.YamlPath


Name        : test-ci
FolderPath  : build
Description : test ci pipeline
Repository  : https://dev.azure.com/******/*****/_git/******
Branch      : prod
Yaml Path   : ./yaml/build.yml

This is the error message that I receive.
az : ERROR: argument --folder-path: expected one argument
At line:1 char:1
+ az pipelines create --name $pipelineName --folder-path $pipelineFolde ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: argument...ed one argument:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

This is my csv file


i tried your script and fix the content. i tried to output each value for confirmation, and add --project for command az pipelines create if it's not predefined. I added the details below, thanks.

You can use -Delimiter "," not ; for csv import.
In addition, please also add --project for your az pipelines create command.

Use command to login: echo PAT | az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/orgname.

With below PowerShell script:


# Import CSV file
$csvData = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\excel\notes.csv" -Delimiter ","

# Loop through each row in the CSV and create a pipeline
foreach ($pipeline in $csvData) {
    # Output each value
    Write-Output "pipelineName: $($pipeline.Name)"
    Write-Output "pipelineFolderPath: $($pipeline.'Folder Path')"
    Write-Output "pipelineDescription: $($pipeline.Description)"
    Write-Output "pipelineRepository: $($pipeline.Repository)"
    Write-Output "pipelineBranch: $($pipeline.Branch)"
    Write-Output "pipelineYamlPath: $($pipeline.'Yaml Path')"

    az pipelines create --name $($pipeline.Name) --folder $($pipeline.'Folder Path') --description $($pipeline.Description) --repository $($pipeline.Repository) --branch $($pipeline.Branch) --yml-path $($pipeline.'Yaml Path') --project {projectname}
    Write-Output "------------------------"

}

The script output:

The pipelines created:

PS: in my script, you can even remove -Delimiter "," for csv import, it's also working.

If your CSV-file is stored in the variable $pipelineVariables then to pick up the Folder Path or Yaml Path (with whitespaces), you would simply:
$pipelineFolderPath = $pipelineVariables."Folder Path"
$pipelineYamlPath = $pipelineVariables."Yaml Path"

Example
Here is a quick example with your CSV-file and data:

First, by just importing it into a variable, I can see that in my case it did not properly create it into a Powershell array of objects:


To solve this -Delimiter ";" is being used:


Example code snippet with foreach loop:


$Csv = Import-Csv .\CreatePipelineExample.csv -Delimiter ";"

foreach ($Pipeline in $Csv) {

  az pipelines create --name $Pipeline.Name --folder-path $Pipeline."Folder Path" --description $Pipeline.Description --repository $Pipeline.Repository --branch $Pipeline.Branch --yml-path $Pipeline."Yaml Path"
}

I hope this helps!
Good luck!

Hi @GalnaGreta, it didn't work for variables with whitespaces by adding the delimeter. Any suggestion?
Btw, it does work if there are no whitespaces.

The delimiter was only to showcase that I needed it while importing the CSV-data.
If you get a proper Powershell object without the delimiter while importing your CSV-data, then you do not need the delimiter.
If you save the CSV-data to your variable called $pipelineVariables, then to reach values with whitespaces it is simply adding quotations while fetching the value like my example are showing:
$pipelineVariables."Folder Path"
$pipelineVariables."Yaml Path"
